# Protecting public firestore data

Tags: wordpress, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firestore to build a quick plugin for Wordpress and Shopify, targeting multiple business owners, therefore using the same Firestore database.

Those are the desired requirements:

- Each website domain is a root document that has identical sub-collections.
  (e.g. /{clientWebsiteName}/recipes). the {clientWebsiteName} is injected by WordPress or Shopify through global js variables, so I guess it would be easy to change its value in the console, that would write to another root document.
- Authentication is either managed by WordPress or Shopify and inject users data through global js variables.
- Admin users can write to all the documents and collections under their root document /{clientWebsiteName}
- Public users can read all the documents and sub-collections but only write on a specific sub-collection.

So I thought of multiple solutions.

1. (The quickest) Using the referer request header in the Firestore rules, (if only it is possible) until now I could not find out how to get the request referer, but I don't think it is even possible. I hope someone could prove me wrong.

```
  match /{root}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if {requestReferer} === root;
  }
```

2. (The unscalable), Using Firestore authentication so that I can protect the data for authenticated users. Hooking in the login WordPress system (not even sure that's possible for Shopify, probably not).

For WordPress, it means using the PHP Firestore SDK, requiring grpc module, so since it is gonna be a plugin, I won't have any control over the clients server. It is gonna be an issue.

3. (The longest) Building a backend that receives the requests, intercepts and will allow or deny those requests, then call Firestore database.

I'm pretty sure it is not as easy as it sounds, and I would have to implement my own real-time logic. And I would probably lose some performances here.

First of all, do I really need to do that?
What would you recommend, or would you recommend something else?

Comment: Judging by the requirements you are sharing, I would say that your only real viable option is to go for number 3 as option 1 I don't think is possible and 2 is ruled out since you mention that you need to manage the authentication through Wordpress or Shopify

Comment: That's what I fear, but then do you think using Firestore is a gain of time in this case? I feel it could be much faster with either a NoSQL database or with an ORM on the backend.